# Spam edits by same user

Tags: support

I had two spam edits from the same user in a short interval: [on this contribution](https://superuser.com/questions/1582977/delete-a-specific-folder-if-it-is-empty-from-batch-file-in-windows/1582986#1582986) and [and this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1585460/cmd-script-using-attrib-h-s-a-q-02-goes-into-a-loop) (which I rolled back). Despite his reputation he (or she) seems to be a rather difficult user (I remember he has been blocked on at least one stackexchange site in the past and I had "bump ins" with him in the past as well). Is there a way to protect/block/etc. myself from such a user? If not what else should I do, what would be appropriate?

Comment: It has been taken care of. If it happens again please flag for a moderator on the affected post.

Comment: Thank you, I will, is it possible to get notified if changes to my posts are done? I think by default I only get a message if the change is "suggested" by a user with less then 2000 rep.

Comment: Unfortunately, notifications are not sent for *minor* edits. See [No notification was received for an edit to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202415/267099)

Comment: I see, so the only solution would be to check all my posts manually (which will be too time consuming)? Also I just realized why he did those edits, he wanted to retract his votes (which he couldn't do without an edit), so hopefully he won't do it again unless he has other upvotes he wants to remove.

Comment: I am not sure, but check the Reactions tab in the Activity tab of your Profile?

Comment: @WasifHasan I don't have a "reactions" tab, I think you mean "Responses", right? That one has a sub tap "revision" which seems to list all revisions made to my questions and answers. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that the time has proved to be enough to explain the event, and for the purpose of avoiding exposure of the condition of members of my family, I prefer to delete the answer, I hope you understand